# Why Can't I instatiate my object in the position that want at unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying instantiate a sphere to use like a bullet. I want that the bullet be align like the image bellow:

[the desirable situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Ay2.png)

but when I instantiate through interactive way a have a problem, The sphere  stay in  diferente coordinate  completely different of that I instantiated previouslly. look at the image:
[the real situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSQnx.png)

why does it happen? how can I solve it?

follow the code from Player.cs:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player 
{
    public string name;
    int currentLife;
    int maxLife;
    int mentalPower;
    public GameObject obj3d; // variável de referência ao modelo 3d do player

    // métodos
    public Player(string nome, int vidaTotal, int forcaMental)
    {
        name = nome;
        maxLife = vidaTotal;
        currentLife = maxLife;
        mentalPower = forcaMental;

    }

    public int Atack(ref bool critico)
    {
        int aux = mentalPower / 2;
        int damage = mentalPower + Random.Range(-aux, aux);
        int critical = Random.Range(0, 100);
        if(critical < 5) // ataque critico 
        {
            critico = true;
            damage *= 2;
        }
        else
        {
            critico = false;

        }
        return (damage);
    }
    public bool UpdateLife(int dano)
    {
        currentLife -= dano;
        if (currentLife < 0)
        {
            //comando para destruir o objeto
            Object.Destroy(obj3d);
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
     public int getLife(int tipo)
    {
        if (tipo == 0)
            return currentLife;
        else
            return maxLife;
    }
     public string getName(Player player)
    {
        return player.name;

    }

}
```

from the Battle.cs:

```
`using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class Battle : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Player[] players;
        int status; // -1= game não começou,0 =game rolando, 1= player 1 vencedor , 2 = player 2 venceu.
        Vector3[] spawnPoints;
        Quaternion[] rotSpawnPoints;
        Color[] playerColors;
        public GameObject myPrefab;
        Text titulo, info, lifePlayer1, lifePlayer2;

        // Bullet
        public GameObject objBullet;
        Vector3  spawBullet;
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            players = new Player[2];
            status = -1;
            spawnPoints = new Vector3[2];
            spawnPoints[0] = new Vector3(2.24f, 0.97f, -4.46f);
            spawnPoints[1] = new Vector3(-6.13f, 0.8f, 3.79f);
            rotSpawnPoints = new Quaternion[2];
            rotSpawnPoints[0] = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, -250.0f, 0.0f);
            rotSpawnPoints[1] = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, -75.0f, 0.0f);
            playerColors = new Color[2];
            playerColors[0] = Color.blue;
            playerColors[1] = Color.red;
            titulo = GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>();
            info = GameObject.Find("Info").GetComponent<Text>();
            lifePlayer1 = GameObject.Find("LifePlayer1").GetComponent<Text>();
            lifePlayer2 = GameObject.Find("LifePlayer2").GetComponent<Text>();
            spawBullet = new Vector3(1.268f, 1.45f, -3.763f);

        }

        void CreatePlayer(int nPlayer)
        {
            print("Entrou na Create Player() com arg = " + nPlayer);
            players[nPlayer - 1].obj3d = (GameObject)Instantiate(myPrefab, spawnPoints[nPlayer - 1], rotSpawnPoints[nPlayer - 1]);
            players[nPlayer - 1].obj3d.name = "Player" + nPlayer;
            players[nPlayer - 1].obj3d.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = playerColors[nPlayer - 1];

            ControlaInterface();
        }
        void ControlaCritico(bool status)
        {
            if (status == true)
            {
                GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>().enabled = true;
                GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>().color = new Color(GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>().color.r, GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>().color.g,
                                                                      GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>().color.b, 255f);
                GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>().text = "CRITOU URRUUU!!!!";
            }
            else
                GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>().enabled = false;


        }
        void ControlaInterface()
        {
            print("entrei na controla inter");
            if(players[0] == null)// entra aqui quando aperta F2
            {
                print("entrou primeiro if");
                GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>().text = "  Aguardando\nPlayer 1 Azul";
                lifePlayer2.enabled = true;
                lifePlayer2.text = players[1].getLife(0).ToString() + "/" + players[1].getLife(1).ToString();
            }
            else if(players[1] == null)// entra aqui quando aperta F1
            {
                print("entrou segundo if");
                GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>().text = "  Aguardando\nPlayer 2 Vemelho";
                lifePlayer1.enabled = true;
                lifePlayer1.text = players[0].getLife(0).ToString() + "/" + players[0].getLife(1).ToString();
            }
            else // player 0 e 1 são diferentes de null
            {
                print("entrou no else");
                lifePlayer2.enabled = true;
                lifePlayer1.enabled = true;
                lifePlayer2.text = players[1].getLife(0).ToString() + "/" + players[0].getLife(1).ToString();
                lifePlayer1.text = players[0].getLife(0).ToString() + "/" + players[1].getLife(1).ToString();
                GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>().enabled = false;
                if (status == -1)
                    status = 0;
            }
            GameObject objTmp = null;

        }
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if (status == -1)
                titulo.color = new Color(titulo.color.r, titulo.color.g, titulo.color.b,Mathf.Sin(Time.time*2.0f +1.0f)/2.0f) ;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F1)) //criar player 1(Azul)
            {
                if (players[0] == null)
                {
                    players[0] = new Player("Player 1 Azul", 100, 14);
                    CreatePlayer(1);
                    //GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>().enabled = false;
                }
            }
            //-4.87f, 0.8f, -4.83f
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F10))// reseta o game
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);

            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F2)) //criar player 2(vermelho)
            {
                if (players[1] == null)
                {
                    players[1] = new Player("Player 2 Vermelho", 100, 14);
                    CreatePlayer(2);
                  //  GameObject.Find("Title").GetComponent<Text>().enabled = false;
                }
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1)) // ataque do player 1
            {
                //if (objTmp == null)
                    GameObject objTmp = (GameObject)Instantiate(objBullet, new Vector3(-0.52f, 0.4f, 0.57f), Quaternion.Euler(0f, -45f, 0f));
                    objTmp.transform.parent = players[0].obj3d.transform;
                    objTmp.transform.localPosition = spawBullet;

                }
            }
            //-4.87f, 0.8f, -4.83f

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2)) //ataque player 2(vermelho)
            {
               // if(objTmp == null)
                GameObject objTmp = (GameObject)Instantiate(objBullet, new Vector3(-4.5f, 0.3f, 5.514f), Quaternion.Euler(0f, -45f, 0f));
                objTmp.transform.parent = players[1].obj3d.transform;
                objTmp.transform.localPosition = spawBullet;
                }


            }
    }
`
```

Comment: as long as your prefab is centred round 0,0,0 it will place exactly where you tell it, if it is not, then it will offset by whatever - tbh I couldnt see enough of a difference to be clear what you felt was wrong, but if you saw spawn here, it will spawn here..

Comment: I think that my prefab is centered round 0,0,0. because prefab is a child of a empty class called "controle"(in english controller). But even so  this problem exist, to be clearest that I can, look at this two images in the links bellow:                   
 what I want is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Ay2.png                                                    but I have been getting  that:                                                                                                      https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSQnx.png

Comment: It maybe clear to you because you know what you are looking at but I dont see what you feel is wrong between the two pictures, and Im usually quite good at spot the difference.  Please make it clear what exactly is not in the right place because I see 2 capsules on a plane, the only difference in the pictures that seems apparent is that one has the plane selected and in the other does not